# Store location of connectionstring EF designer

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

In visual studio 2017 I have a database project with an EF-6 model (edmx). When I open the designer, it shows me a connectionstring, but for some reason I cannot find this in any projectfile (searched app.config, web.config, ...).

Is there some other place where this connectionstring is stored? Because I want to modify it, but it is hard to modify something you cannot find.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself and it could be helpfull, so I'll answer my own question.

In visual studio you have a server explorer window. Probably all EF connections will be stored inside the "Data Connections" of this Server explorer. If you remove them, they will not show up anymore in the EF wizard.

Found another solution for a problem worth to post here. The wizard was crashing when I tried to connect to a MySql database. It was just a mismatch in all versions of MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity and the installed MySql connector. Make sure all the versions match each other, then it will work perfectly